# How to get the total value of to two rand() variables that match on the input value of a text form?

Tags: php, validation, random, input

I found out that whenever I press submit button it does change the current value of the rand() the reason why it doesn't match on my input value.

I want to use this as validation to my form. Before the user can submit the message he/she must answer the question first.

here is my code:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    $numa  = rand(1,5);
    $numb = rand(0,4);
    $_SESSION['valid_res'] = $numa + $numb;
echo 'Answer this '.$numa . ' + ' . $numb .' = '; 
    ?>

    <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <input type="text" name="input" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(intval($_POST['input']) != $_SESSION['valid_res']){
            echo 'You enter have entered '. intval($_POST['input']) .' it is wrong answer';
            }else{
                echo 'Congratulations you have entered '. intval($_POST['input']) .' it is the correct answer.';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the session value on each page load. Write it only on first load and use the subsequent value for the check.
You also have to convert the session variable to integer form.
Try this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $numa  = rand(1,5);
    $numb = rand(0,4);
    $_SESSION['valid_res'] = $numa + $numb;
    echo 'Answer this '.$numa . ' + ' . $numb .' = '; 
}
else
    if(intval($_POST['input']) != intval($_SESSION['valid_res']))
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. But still get the problem. I cannot get the total value. When I tried to submit, the value of rand() and the total have changed everytime it refresh the reason it does not match. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `!==` instead of `!=`. Use the code below

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $numa  = rand(1,5);
    $numb = rand(0,4);
    $_SESSION['valid_res'] = $numa + $numb;
echo 'Answer this '.$numa . ' + ' . $numb .' = '; 
    ?>

    <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <input type="text" name="input" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(intval($_POST['input']) !==$_SESSION['valid_res']){
            echo 'You enter have entered '. intval($_POST['input']) .' it is wrong answer';
            }else{
                echo 'Congratulations you have entered '. intval($_POST['input']) .' it is the correct answer.';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. But still get the problem. I cannot get the total value. When I tried to submit, the value of rand() and the total have changed everytime it refresh the reason it does not match. :(